# How do you measure the performance of applying css to text?

Tags: webkit, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, blink

I am currently facing a performance question with CCS on different browsers (blink and webkit).

In order to perform an analysis regarding "How long does it take to see glow around text after click", I need some advice how to correctly profile this with the developer tools.

I do not see an option to get differences between the start of my click and the end of a rectangle paint like shown in the attached screen shot.

[image]

As a code example, please see here:

```
# code on jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1y4emzc/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a 'Profiles' tab in dev tools. Select 'Collect JavaScript CPU Profile', then hit Start button, click the 'Click to Highlight' button you have and then hit Stop button. You can then see the details of timings in milliseconds.

[image]